# How to run a Maven JME project in netbeans?

Tags: java, maven-2, netbeans, java-me

I have created a maven project with j2me-archetype using netbeans. It creates a project with a default MIDLet (SampleMIDlet.java). 
But when I try to run the project it says that No Main Class Found. Can anyone tell that why it is going for Main class instead of existing Midlet ?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I'm not sure what you mean exactly by "How to run a Maven JME project in netbeans". I'm not a JME expert but, to my knowledge, to run such a project, you'll need a ***Java ME MIDP Platform Emulator***. Do you have that emulator installed? Maybe have a look at the [FaqJavaMESDKinstall](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqJavaMESDKinstall).

Comment: Yes I have it installed. I solved it in a way that i created nebeans midp project and added a pom file to it - and it more or less works.